# How to solve this pde equation: xp(1+q) = (y+z)q

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

By Charpit Method, I am getting $p=\dfrac{a(y+z)}{1+ax}$ and $q=ax$.

Here $p=\dfrac{dz}{dx}$ and $q=\dfrac{dz}{dy}$

$z$ is the dependent variable while $x$ and $y$ are independent variables.

Following i have this: $dz=\dfrac{a(y+z)}{1+ax}dx + axdy$, which I can not integrate.

Comment: Please define $p,q$ and please type in latex for better representation.

Comment: Duplicate of  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378894/partial-differential-equation-xp1q-yzq

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Thank you for your suggestion. I am not able to integrate the last equation to get the value of z.